# how to combine the two queries sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Good day.

I have two sql query:

**First:**

```
SELECT name FROM 
TableOne
WHERE city='3452' AND firm='49581' AND service='2'
Group by name
```

**Second:**

```
SELECT name FROM 
TableTwo
WHERE city='3452' AND firm='49581' AND service='2'
Group by name
```

*Tell me please how to combine the two queries sql and select all name (with group by name) from two tables ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` http://sqltutorials.blogspot.com/2007/06/sql-union-all.html

```
SELECT name
FROM (
    SELECT name 
    FROM TableOne
    WHERE city='3452' AND firm='49581' AND service='2'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name 
    FROM TableTwo
    WHERE city='3452' AND firm='49581' AND service='2' ) x
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: See Branko's answer for a more terse solution if you're filtering on the same columns and values for each of the sub queries.  The performance between the two solutions should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `UNION` operator between two queries. According to answer in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588913/select-data-from-two-tables-with-identical-columns):

> You may be looking at using a UNION in you query:

```
Select * from a UNION Select * from b Note:
```

> It is better practice to
>   qualify your column names instead of using the * reference. This would
>   also make the query still useful if your two tables underwent schema
>   changes but you still wanted to pull back all the data the two tables
>   had in common.

`Union` will rule out same objects. To avoid that you can use `UNION ALL` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Well, "combine" can mean a lot of things, but I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
SELECT name
FROM (
    SELECT name, city, firm, service FROM TableOne
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name, city, firm, service FROM TableTwo
) Q
WHERE city='3452' AND firm='49581' AND service='2'
GROUP BY name
```

There is no need to use UNION (without ALL), since GROUP BY will remove the duplicates anyway.

BTW, are all these fields used in the WHERE clause really strings? If not, you'd want to remove single quotes as appropriate. It's a bit suspicious that you are using string literals that contain only numbers.

Comment: You'll need to select `city`, `firm`, and `service` in your sub queries.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this syntax is a little simpler and thus easier to maintain. The comma in line two does a join.

```
SELECT name FROM 
TableOne, TableTwo
WHERE city='3452' AND firm='49581' AND service='2'
Group by name
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think this works in SQL Server 2008. Don't you get an `Ambiguous Column Name 'name'` error?

Comment: @Greg No ambiguous column error will occur since the names of the two columns used in the join are identical. According to [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918570/what-is-the-difference-between-using-a-cross-join-and-putting-a-comma-between-the-two-tables) The CROSS JOIN became ANSI standard in SQL:1992, vs the ANSI SQL:1989 syntax using commas.

Comment: @Marichyasana I'm not doubting the cross join (although I'd argue it's not as easy to understand or as self documenting as the union) but I'm 90% sure that you can't just `SELECT name` without getting an error as name is defined in both tables. It can't resolve which column to return.